# Weekend Extra: Come watch Digimon Tri 1-4 with us!

Tags: discussion, community-events

For all of this weekend, come watch Digimon Tri and other anime with us.

[Series Info](http://www.crunchyroll.com/forumtopic-927739/crunchyroll-presents-digimon-adventure-tri)

I'll be holding multiple streams of the series on Crunchyroll, via [rabb.it](http://www.rabb.it/Krazer) sessions starting 0500 UTC, this Saturday thru Sunday. The format will be causual and anyone can join at any time, starting 0200 UTC. As an warm up to the event, I'll be showing select [Animator Expo](http://animatorexpo.com/) shorts to give users a chance to file and get ready for the main feature (at 0500 UTC).

There will another concurrent session play for latecomers as well. After the movie, for those that wish to stay and binge some more, you'll have your choice of selections from:

- Space Battleship Yamato 2199
- Bodacious Space Pirates
- Mushishi
- The Second Patlabor movie
- Wolf Children
- Any else you'd like to watch

If you can't make is Saturday, come Sunday we'll probably be up all night and morning watching and discussing stuff.