# Anime Weekend Extra: Come watch anime with us!

Tags: discussion, community-events

On March 12th and 13th we'll be having our next anime viewing event with Anime.SE's Basement Anime Club. The session will start on the 12th of March at 0500 UTC and continue until it dies on Sunday. People are welcome to come and join as they please. If there is something you'd like to watch we'll try to find it and put it on for you!

We invite you to join us as we watch and discuss anime!

This session will take place in my Rabbit room: http://www.rabb.it/giraffesyo

During a previous session, we watched the first part of *Digimon Adventure tri.* Crunchyroll will be streaming the [second part](http://myanimelist.net/anime/32108/Digimon_Adventure_tri_2__Ketsui) of this series when it releases on Saturday.

Some other anime that are available for our streaming session are:

- *[Now and Then, Here and There](http://myanimelist.net/anime/160/Ima_Soko_ni_Iru_Boku)*
- [*Patlabor* (the series)](http://myanimelist.net/anime/324/Mobile_Police_Patlabor)
- *[My-Otome](http://myanimelist.net/anime/99/Mai-Otome)*
- *[Ping Pong the Animation](http://myanimelist.net/anime/22135/Ping_Pong_The_Animation)*
- *[Memories](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1462/Memories)*

And more! Let us know what you want to watch in an answer!

Link to previous session meta post: [Weekend Extra: Come watch Digimon Tri 1-4 with us!](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2676/17758)

Answer (score 2):

The weekend anime extra event has now concluded!

During which we completed watching:

- *[Gate](http://myanimelist.net/anime/31637/Gate__Jieitai_Kanochi_nite_Kaku_Tatakaeri_2nd_Season)* (Episodes 21 and 22)
- *[Kanojo to Kanojo no Neko: Everything Flows](http://myanimelist.net/anime/32491/Kanojo_to_Kanojo_no_Neko__Everything_Flows)* (Episode 2)
- *[Digimon Adventure tri. 2: Ketsui](http://myanimelist.net/anime/32108/Digimon_Adventure_tri_2__Ketsui)*
- *[Space Pirate Captain Harlock](http://myanimelist.net/anime/17269/Captain_Harlock)*
- *[Mai-Otome](http://myanimelist.net/anime/99/Mai-Otome)*
- *[Mai-Otome Specials](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1659/Mai-Otome_Specials)*
- *[Mai-Otome Special: Otome no Inori](http://myanimelist.net/anime/8518/Mai-Otome_Special__Otome_no_Inori)*
- *[Battle Programmer Shirase](http://myanimelist.net/anime/579/Battle_Programmer_Shirase)*
- *[Paprika](http://myanimelist.net/anime/1943/Paprika)*

Thank you [Krazer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/63/%CA%9E%C9%B9%C9%90z%C7%9D%C9%B9), [Josh McMahan](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/18881/josh-mcmahan), [Tyhja](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/6481/tyhja),  [Quill](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/13959/quill), [Yokhen](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2793/yokhen), Light Yagami, Shinobu, and a few others who came and enjoyed the show. Make sure to stay tuned for our next event!